# Closing Tkinter window and opening another

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to build a simple hangman game. I want to have a window at the beginning to ask for the "secret word". I then want that window to close and have another window open with the game. I can't think of a way to do this without building the entire game within a funciton. How is best to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is a `Toplevel` window and it behaves just like a normal root window. Below is a quick and dirty example:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Game window")
root.iconify()#Hide from user site, still exists as a minimised window


def submitSecretWord():
    #code to collect secret word or what ever
    root.deiconify()#Make visible
    second_window.destroy()#close second window


#make toplevel window
second_window = tk.Toplevel(master=root)


#make widgets
secret_word_entry = tk.Entry(master=second_window)#Belongs to the second window

submit_button = tk.Button(master=second_window, text="Submit secret word", command=submitSecretWord) #Belongs to the second window

#pack widgets
secret_word_entry.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
submit_button.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This wasn't exactly what I wanted, but your comment helped a ton! I didn't know about the deiconify function and that worked perfectly to allow me to have the game running and bring it up after the secret word was entered. Thanks so much!

Answer (score -1):

Create another window? Try this:

use multiple functions

```py
from tkinter import *
from turtle import onclick


def gameWindow(word):
    window = Tk()
    Label(text=word).pack()
    # your game code

    def anotherGuess():
        window.destroy()
        getWord()
    Button(text='another guess?', command=anotherGuess).pack()
    window.mainloop()


def getWord():
    window = Tk()
    entry = Entry(master=window)
    entry.pack()

    def onclick():
        word = entry.get()
        window.destroy()
        gameWindow(word)
    btn = Button(master=window, text="submit", command=onclick)
    btn.pack()
    window.mainloop()


def main():
    getWord()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```